# Tomcat HTTP to HTTPS redirection

Tags: java, http, tomcat, encryption, https

I tried to redirect HTTP traffic thru HTTPS in apache Tomcat 8.0.23.
When doing a BASIC authentication and monitoring traffic thru TCP monitor observed below points.

1. When its HTTP user password id shown in plain text – ok
2. When its HTTPS user password id shown is encrypted – ok
3. **When I try to redirect I am not seeing anything  related to userid /pwd (either encoded or encypted)why ? Below is what I am seeing.**

Output per point 3
[image]

Output per point 2 (underlined encrypted text)
[image]

As per Point 1
[image]